# Home Drive Creation Issue

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have PowerShell a script to create a new user's home drive and I am using below command:

```
Set-ADUser $User -HomeDrive $driveLetter -HomeDirectory $fullPath
```

It's creating the home drive for the user but the user isn't able to access it.

One more thing, I can copying the created home drive manually from AD console and again pasting it and clicking on apply then it works fine.

Comment: What does the last sentence mean? copy and paste was from ADUC to where? The permissions?  Have you checked the perms?

Comment: Please explain what is in variable `$user`. Is that the users SamAccountName, the objectGUID or SID or the users DistinguishedName ?

Comment: Does the user get a permissions error, and if so, what is that error?

Comment: It seems like the ACLs on the homepath are missing. Once you check the permissions and see the user has no rights you'll be good to go.

Comment: In $user i am passing the user's SamAccountName.

Comment: Whenever i am executing the command "Set-ADUser $User -HomeDrive $driveLetter -HomeDirectory $fullPath" and $user -> SamAccountName and $fullpath -> user's location with SamAccountName as suffix and it is only displaying the home drive path value in AD user console but it is not accessible by User itself.

Answer (score 0):

Set-ADUser will only modify the user object in ActiveDirectory; security permissions on the folder itself is an additional step.

[FileSystemRights Enumeration: MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemrights?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0)

It is not sufficient to simply use Set-ADUser, expecting full end to end creation of a fully functioning home directory; we must set permissions on the folder in question, including any inheritance flags.

There's a few steps to accomplish this, but simply stated:
We need to get the current access control list (ACL)
We need to add our desired permissions to said ACL
We need to write the new ACL, combining both the pre-existing and new permissions.

As you may have guessed:

Get-ACL
Set-ACL

We can so something like this:

```
Set-ADUser $User -HomeDrive $driveLetter -HomeDirectory $fullPath -ea Stop
$homeShare = New-Item -path $fullPath -ItemType Directory -force -ea Stop

$acl = Get-Acl $homeShare

$FileSystemRights = [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]"Modify"
$AccessControlType = [System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType]::Allow
$InheritanceFlags = [System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]"ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit"
$PropagationFlags = [System.Security.AccessControl.PropagationFlags]"InheritOnly"

$AccessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule ($User.SID, $FileSystemRights, $InheritanceFlags, $PropagationFlags, $AccessControlType)
$acl.AddAccessRule($AccessRule)

Set-Acl -Path $homeShare -AclObject $acl -ea Stop
```

If you're feeling creative, you can also combine some of the flags into an array:

```
$InheritanceFlag = @('ContainerInherit','ObjectInherit')
```

Please note this code is *NOT* tested and to validate before executing in any environment.